# What role, if any, did the Chinese Communist Party play in the Soviet invasion of Xinjiang?

Tags: soviet-union, japan, china

The Soviets invaded Xinjiang [to support their client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_invasion_of_Xinjiang), a warlord who had no connection to the CCP.

Did the CCP support this invasion? Oppose it? Or just try to avoud talking about it?

Related: were the Soviets actively supporting the Kuomintang in skirmishes against Japan at this time?

Comment: I suppose because their sponsor country was a threat to the country that they wanted to rule. This seems like an embarrassment, in the same sense that Oswald Mosley's support from/to the Nazis was an embarrassment.

Comment: That's quite an exaggeration. Had the Soviets invaded China proper I would agree, but fostering a at the time anti-Nationalist warlord in Sinkiang, which was not historic Chinese territory, wasn't much cause for concern.

Comment: The Soviets sent 7000 troops, the Kuomintang 13,000, according to WP. That suggests they were gravely concerned, and the article says there were 'heavy' casualties on both sides. Of course, sometimes things don't have the profile one might imagine they had, and maybe the invasion made no difference to the CCP either way. However, it seems reasonable to think it might have.

Comment: 13,000 *regional* troops already in the area, which is nothing. The KMT had 2,200,000 in 1928.

Comment: With respect, I can't really square the idea of not caring about it with marching people to their deaths over it. Perhaps I'm just naïve